# How to get in-app purchase localizations approved after they have been 'Waiting for Review' for over a month?

Tags: localization, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

We launched an iPad app in the app store nearly 2 months ago that included in-app purchases of an auto-renewable subscription.  The in-app purchases were approved along with some but not all of the localizations.  The remaining localizations have been stuck in 'Waiting for review' for nearly 2 months, even while multiple other releases of this app have been approved.  How can I trigger Apple to review the localizations?

[screenshot of German and English localizations stuck in 'waiting for review'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akVj2.png)

During the process of first submitting the app, the app was returned, and then approved, but we didn't realize we had to re-attach the in-app purchases, so they were not included in the approval.  We had to resubmit a new build to resubmit the in-app purchases.  It seemed like it worked, but only half of the localizations were approved.

Last week we tried adding another localization (to French) with the hope this would trigger the German and English localizations to be approved.  Unfortunately only the new French one was approved.

I have mentioned the localizations on subsequent app review submissions, but no change.  I have written to Apple Developer Support but they haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: This doesn't look like a programming issue, so might be more appropriate for an app store discussion forum.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I filed a developer support ticket from Apple and it was eventually approved.  There was no other way to fix this in App Store Connect.